# What influences the speed of DVD copying to hard drive

Tags: dvd

I have hundreds of DVDs with movies that nowadays seem less and less useful to keep. I mean the medium but not the content.

The best solution from software point of view I found HandBreak which is recommended for this kind of things. The problem I'm facing now in digitizing it is  time required to copy content to hard drive. Currently it's taking more o less the time of the movie itself so for me it would be over a month of constant reading on my regular laptop (integrated GPU, i5, 8GB RAM).

I'd like to ask what component (if any) the most influence speed of copying. I know that there is also a read speed of DVD reader, but I don't think much can be done in this area since speeds of drives are rather similar.

**Edit with use case explained**

Since it is not clear (even by myself) if mentioned transcoding or cloning is appropriate term here I'd like to explain my main use case.

I want to clone/transcode (I'll use c/t abbreviation later for that) my DVDs to some format. Only requirements that I have is to keep subtitles and the movie itself. Rest can be gone.
Once movie is c/t it'll be stored n some NAS (QNAP, Synlogy etc.). At that point details are starting to be a little bit unclear. Either I want to use built-in software or find something extra, or even play with some RPi solution. Overall I want to be able to stream those stored videos to any device so I can watch it for example while I'm on the go or on vacation.

I know that some of NAS has transcoding capabilities. In that case I assume simple cloning will do. But at the same time this is significant reducing number of my choices to only devices that have such capability. This is why I'd like to have some versatile and fast solution to transfer my DVDs to any (or almost any) NAS.

Comment: If you're using Handbreak, then you're not just copying but ***transcoding*** the video.  That turns an I/O intensive job into a computational intensive job.  So CPU and GPU capability plus RAM availability are what matter.

Comment: If I were you, put all the DVDs in a large binder and toss the cases. The DVDs are the only profile you own the contents.

Comment: @Keltari Keeping the paper covers from the DVD cases might be nice too, they usually just slide out, or if they're cardboard and form part of the case then cutting off the plastic bits works too. And probably OT, but would obtaining digital copies of the movies then be 100% safe/legal?

Comment: @Xen2050 not necessarily. They would have to be the *exact* same version. And downloading a torrent, even if it's the same and you in it, is illegal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in copying these movies ("ripping DVDs") to your computer, and not transcoding the video as you currently are doing. As @sawdust explained, Handbrake does not copy 1:1, but is a transcoder. By purely ripping without transcoding, you'll finish moving over your collection faster and preserve video/audio quality, DVD menus, extras, etc. (if you so choose), at the expense of needing more disk space. There are programs like [CloneDVD](https://www.redfox.bz/en/clonedvd.html) that can  help you with this.

To answer your question more directly, purely copying DVDs to hard drive is almost always limited by the speed of the DVD drive. In your case however, the addition of transcoding by Handbrake changes this question to not just copying, but transcoding. In such a case, many additional factors including CPU, GPU, RAM may be the limiting cause.

### EDIT

After understanding your circumstances a little better, I would say ripping 1:1 copies is probably faster than transcoding ("re-encoding") with Handbrake for the reasons already stated. How much faster I cannot say without testing with your machine.

Comment: @K7AAY would doing the "work" on a remote computer actually be faster, after the network transfer times? I guess it would depend on how slow/fast the computers & network are, but if the network adds minutes... maybe there's a baseline network speed

Comment: Since laptops are often not speed demons, you may benefit by using a remote access app to control a desktop or a server which does the actual ripping or transcoding, then transfer the results en masse when you're away from the laptop (or just serve up the media as needed). Here's a list of such remote control apps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software